# Firebase dependencies causing error at runtime

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbwa`

**gradle(app)**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

**gradle(project)**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in another dependencie with the packpage `com.google.android.gms`

Sample:

```
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.x') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Error was removed by using exclude group with dependencies.

```
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```